# OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect libraries

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

What are best options for OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect Open Source libraries with C# (.NET) Implementation.

I know few, but they are either OAuth 2.0 or other but not both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenID Foundation keeps a list of libraries/products here: http://openid.net/developers/libraries/ IdentityServer3 implements both OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect in C#.